How to achieve this layout with dynamic Divider heights in Jetpack Compose?
I want to achieve the layout below with two vertical dividers and a circle in a Column. Here is my code so far:
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.zIndex(100 - dataModel.currentStep.toFloat())
) {
    Row(
        Modifier
            .background(color = Color.Green)
            .padding(8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
    ) {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxHeight(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Divider(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp), color = Color.Black)
            Circle()
            Divider(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp), color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Circle() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(24.dp)
            .background(color = colorResource(R.color.turquoise).copy(alpha = 0.3f), CircleShape)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(12.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .background(color = colorResource(R.color.turquoise), CircleShape)
        )
    }
}

How to make the dividers take the needed space vertically without giving them a specific height, since I want this to be dynamic?


Please also provide the Circle composable.

I've edited my question.

Dividers won't work because they would not overlay the outer circle. Instead you can use a Column with a background color that contains the Circle. To make the Circle bigger than the Column you need to use requiredSize.
Everything put together:
@Composable
fun StepIndicator(
    circleSize: Dp,
    lineThickness: Dp,
    color: Color,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    // container
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .padding(horizontal = (circleSize - lineThickness) / 2),
    ) {
        // vertical line
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = color)
                .width(lineThickness)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            // outer circle
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredSize(circleSize)
                    .background(color = color.copy(alpha = 0.3f), shape = CircleShape),
            ) {
                // inner circle
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(circleSize / 2)
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                        .background(color = color, shape = CircleShape),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

This is an example of three StepIndicators with different heights:
val circleSize = 24.dp
val lineThickness = 2.dp
val colorTurquoise = colorResource(R.color.turquoise)

Column {
    StepIndicator(circleSize, lineThickness, colorTurquoise)
    StepIndicator(circleSize, lineThickness, colorTurquoise, Modifier.height(100.dp))
    StepIndicator(circleSize, lineThickness, colorTurquoise, Modifier.height(200.dp))
}

And this is how it looks:

